# Looking for an online mathematics practice resource

Tags: undergraduate-education, reference-request, self-learning

Forgive me if this is off topic, but I've been looking for an online resource that I can use to polish up and improve my math skills. I've looked at math.com and purplemath.com but they don't have much past algebra. I want to know if there is a site that contains "complete" coursework for Trigonometry, Calculus, and possibly Statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) is what you're looking for. As far as introductory mathematics university courses go, it has plenty of resources. Certainly it covers Trigonometry, Geometry and Calculus well enough.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm a special kind of idiot. I've been searching places like MIT"s OCW and completely forgot about this... Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @slow_excellence Glad to have been of help. Remember Math.SE is your friend for your questions. =)

Comment: Yup! I'm already a member there, just needed some review problems to get started with haha.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com) for lots of problems (but perhaps most harder than what you are looking for). Look at the relevant tags. Search for math olympiad preparation material, and for problems and solutions in such. Again, probably much harder than what you are interested in for a first look,